# Email Studio - Social Share Buttons custom functionality

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-studio

I've been attempting to have the Marketing Cloud social share buttons mimic the result of an external tool (such as Canva). The intended function is to have the email content or image (with a given subscriber's name) printed into the body of a social media post, most importantly LinkedIn.

From what I've tested with OpenGraph, it looks like this type of scenario would require a custom integration making use of LinkedIn's API since they have an endpoint that seems to handle this (image/text injection into post body). OpenGraph only allows me to control the preview/article contents, not input content directly into the body of the post.

I'm curious if anyone here has had any luck with a solution for a similar case, prior to looking into external tools to handle this process.

(side note: I did create custom buttons for testing with OpenGraph, and didn't use the standard ones as I found no way to manipulate those)

Thank you,